# Change the Increment Value of a SapUI5 Input (type: Number)

Tags: sapui5

I want to change the increment step of a Input control in SapUI5 when pressing the Up and Down Arrows, but i wasn't able to find such a property in the documentation.

```
<Input type="Number" value="{/config/value}" liveChange="onPriceChange"
               editable="true"/>
```

Is there something like the "step" property for Input in HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no "step" property in SAPUI5 as the sap.m.Input of type "Number" exactly relies on HTML5 input. Probably you can update "step" property in the DOM element.

Comment: I managed to do it by adding the step attribute with jQuery to the DOM element, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use property [step](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.StepInput.html#setStep) of [sap.m.StepInput](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.StepInput.html) instead.